# How to install Azure SDK 2.9.6 for VIsual Studio 2015 Community after Web Platform Installer retiring

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, microsoft, sdk, web-platform-installer

I am trying to install Microsoft Azure SDK 2.9.6 for Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. When I go to Tools -> Extensions and Updates and click the update button on the Azure SDK 2.9.6 I am directed to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=746481 to download VWDOrVs2015AzurePack.2E2.2E9.exe. When I run the executable Web Platform Installer 5.1 opens to the spotlight tab with a message saying

> Microsoft Web Platform Installer couldn't find the product you tried to install. Either the link you clicked is incorrect or you may be overriding your feed with a different feed.

Below that is a link that is labeled that it will help learning more about custom feeds and to reset Web Platform Installer, but clicking it leads to go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=255182 which redirects to a http only www dot webmatrix dot com which is an advertisement for some product. Going to the Products tab in Web Platform Installer yields a

> There are no products or applications available to install in any of the categories.

A lot of places have suggestions, but they don't solve the problem and I don't see how they would ever work given this blogpost: https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/web-platform-installer-end-of-support-feed. The final entry in the timeline presented in this blogpost is:

> December 31st, 2022 - The WebPI feed will be removed from the servers and the product installers will be pulled from the Microsoft download center

Below this is a short Q&A:

> Q:  What if I still need something from WebPI to maintain a legacy system?
>
> A:  Take a look at creating a WebPI Offline Feed - you can setup a mini WebPI feed and installer repository locally that will allow you to continue to deploy products to legacy machines.  Remember to download and store copies of the WebPI installer itself (both x86 and x64) as those will be removed per the dates above.

It's now the middle of 2023 and never received this news as I was just handed this project. I'm interpreting "product installers will be pulled from the Microsoft download center" to mean all the products that could be downloaded with WPI. If this doesn't mean that, where would they be hosted? If it's web application gallery it looks like that's been retired July 1st, 2021 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/develop/windows-web-application-gallery/frequently-asked-questions). Is there an archive of https://webgallery.microsoft.com? Are these products hosted or were hosted somewhere else? I can't find nor not sure where the SDK would be at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/. I looked at the azure links, but it just goes to documentation and trying to download other software listed on other previous-versions documentation 404s. I look at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/ but I don't find a generic Azure SDK. I assume the SDK I need is .NET so when I go there https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/releases/latest/dotnet.html I also can't find the Azure SDK. Searching the website or deprecated for Azure SDK or 2.9.6 or Azure tools or Azure app service does not find the SDK. If all else fails would anyone know where there is an archive with an offline version of some variant of the Azure SDK 2.9.6 installer such as a split up version like Azure SDK 2.8.2 (for reference https://web.archive.org/web/20200804144739/https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50041)?

Unrelated, but I was originally at Azure SDK 2.7 when I started and I found cached installers cached by WPI a long time ago at `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers`. I was able to get to Azure SDK 2.9 using those installers, but I still need to get to Azure SDK 2.9.6.

EDIT: Anyone have at least a backup of the cached lists in `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\preprocessor`? One of them may contain a microsoft download link and other installations actions for 2.9.6. The link will probably 404, but there may be an archive of it on internet archive or other (I also tried search to search the internet archive for Azure SDK 2.9.6 and I couldn't find it).

Comment: Yes; Microsoft did indeed discontinue and pull the installation files for this product. Even if you found an archive copy, it sounds like the installation files, were web installers. Without the Microsoft backend they can’t be used.